# Is there a way I can add single event listener to cover multiple?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have something that happens whenever the user moves, so for this I set the three event listeners:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.doThing)
document.addEventListener('click', this.doThing)
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.doThing)
```

Which do also eventually need to be removed:

```
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.doThing)
document.removeEventListener('click', this.doThing)
document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.doThing)
```

The thing is, they are all doing the exact same thing, so I was wondering if there is a better way to group these into a single add and remove event listener. Or perhaps if there is one that covers any movement/interaction of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly do something like:

```
["mousemove", "click", "keydown"].forEach(evt => document.addEventListener(evt, this.doThing));
["mousemove", "click", "keydown"].forEach(evt => document.removeEventListener(evt, this.doThing));
```

Simple generic version with lambdas could be:

```
let addHandlers = (events, handler) => events.forEach(evt => document.addEventListener(evt, handler))
let removeHandlers = (events, handler) => events.forEach(evt => document.addEventListener(evt, handler))
addHandlers(["mousemove", "click"], this.doThing);
removeHandlers(["mousemove", "click"], this.doThing);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a space-separated string of events and loop through each. Most libraries, like [`jQuery.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), do something similar.

```
function setEventsToDocument(events, callback) {
  events.split(' ').forEach(event => {
    document.addEventListener(event, callback)
  })
}

function removeEventsFromDocument(events, callback) {
  events.split(' ').forEach(event => {
    document.removeEventListener(event, callback)
  })
}

setEventsToDocument('mousemove click keydown', callback)

removeEventsFromDocument('mousemove click keydown', callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a [`handleEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent) member function and provide `this` as the event handler:

```js
class Thing {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.el.addEventListener("mouseover", this);
    this.el.addEventListener("click", this);
  }
  handleEvent(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
      case "mouseover":
        console.log("mouseover");
        break;
      case "click":
        console.log("click");
        break;
    }
  }
};

const thing = new Thing(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

```html
<button id="foo">Hello</button>
```